# What is the difference between the regular Oracle ADO Provider and the Oracle Web ASP Provider?

Tags: oracle, ado.net

I am migrating off of Microsoft's OracleConnection class for a asp.net-mvc website given that its being deprecated.  I see on the [oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html), there are 2 different options, one is the Oracle ADO Provider for .Net 4 and the other is Oracle ADO ASP Provider for .Net 4.  I am trying to figure out the difference because the code that I use to access Oracle in my site is not web specific (its sitting in a different project to the main MVC project and I plan on using this library in desktop apps as well).

Can someone explain the difference between these two libraries and advise on which one I should use for my situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle website can be a problem! :)

The [ADO provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) is the standard data access code for Oracle from .NET:

> Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET) features optimized ADO.NET
> data access to the Oracle database. ODP.NET allows developers to take
> advantage of advanced Oracle database functionality, including
>
> Real Application Clusters
>
> XML DB

The [Oracle Providers for ASP.NET you mention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-087367.html), is a specific release for helping with things like ASP.NET State Management, Membership and Roles:

> ASP.NET provider developers will discover the
> Oracle Providers for ASP.NET are easy to learn and use as they share a
> common schema and API with existing ASP.NET providers. They integrate
> seamlessly with existing ASP.NET services and controls, just like
> other ASP.NET providers.
>
> Oracle offers the following providers:
>
> Membership Provider
>
> Role Provider
>
> Site Map Provider
>
> Session State Provider...

Comment: ah . . so given that it seems like the regular (not the ASP) version is what i should use

Comment: Yes, it would seem so. Although if you're using ASP.NET membership etc then using the ASP.NET version may be useful too.

Comment: agree . . as I mentioned, the connection and queries are all simple and not connected to any of the provider functions listed above.  again thanks for the clarification